# Does a refusal for a US B1/B2 visa adversely affect my chances of getting a Canadian Student visa

Tags: usa, canada

I had applied for a `B1/B2` visa, which was denied. Now I want to pursue further studies in Canada.

I'm wondering if a denied visitor visa to the `US` will adversely affect the chances of me getting a student visa in Canada?

Comment: What is your nationality? Why were you denied the tourist visa? Do you have an acceptance from a reputed Canadian university?

Comment: @nikhil Should that say reputable?

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly it may affect, as no documentation states that US Tourist Visa refusal will automatically straight-forward effect Canada Study Visa.

But.. Canada & US are members of five-eye group, mainly to share criminal-immigration related data, but who knows they also share normal visa refusals also? Canada Study Visa form will ask you about any refusal/deportation by any country (in past 10 years?), so ideally you should be stating about this B1/B2.

At same time, same as US, Canada will also look for your ties to your home-land, & will want to make sure that you have enough reasons to leave Canada & come back once you finish the studies. Also, that you have legal & adequate financial resources to support you there & you will nor be a burden on welfare or that you will not be resorting to work illegally.

So, to re-iterate, no, it does not have any automatic direct affect, it will not be the automatic reason for Canada refusal, but the same reasons US considered to refuse you the B1/B2 visa, may come up & affect the outcome of this Study Visa application. If none of your circumstances changed, Canadian reasons might be the exact same.

Provided you show/prove enough ties/finances by legal/honest way (not fund parking etc.) to elevate Visa Officer's concerns, he/she may get convinced & can give you the visa. Then, although you did not asked, once you are in Canada on study, if you genuinely want to visit US as a tourist, having Canada Study Visa (along-with other things) may positively effect that outcome.

Comment: And who's to say that the US visa refusal was not "normal"?  For all we know, it might have been refused because of some criminal matter.  You seem to have gotten your affect/effect backward.  Otherwise +1.

Comment: @phoog yes agree, but still, having US Visa refused will not be the reason Canada will also refuse. Canada will never say "We refuse because US refused" in refusal notice. Yes, if US refused for something criminal (or even ties/finances), Canada will/may also say "We refuse you for this xyz criminality (or ties/finaces)". Also, will fix affect/effect :)

Comment: @phoog, yes, I mean that it is documented that they share "criminal" data between 5-eyes, and I mean they "may" also share the other types of data also. So, in any case, not disclosing this on Visa form when asked may cause more damage.

Comment: I agree. What I meant was that *if* there are circumstances that would have negative impact on the Canadian visa application, the US refusal might increase the probability of Canada learning of those circumstances. (On the other hand, if the US refused because the application failed to establish a valid purpose for the trip, that should have little or no impact on a student visa application, since the trip and its purpose are completely different.)